# SQLAlchemy ORM search through multiple relationships for an attribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I know it's possible to filter an initial query by a relational attribute (see [SqlAlchemy - Filtering by Relationship Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561470/sqlalchemy-filtering-by-relationship-attribute))

But what about after you've already retrieved the object?

Given:

```
class Parks(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parks'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    state = Column(String(2))
    city = Column(String)
    zipcode = Column(String, index=True)

    alerts = relationship('Alerts', back_populates='park')


class Alerts(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'alerts'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    park_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parks.id'))
    alert_type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('alert_types.id'))
    alert_message = Column(String)

    park = relationship('Parks', back_populates="alerts")
    alert_type = relationship('AlertTypes', back_populates='alerts')


class AlertTypes(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'alert_types'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    alert_type_long_des = Column(String)

    alerts = relationship('Alerts', back_populates='alert_type')
```

I know I can do

```
park_closed_alert = session.query(AlertTypes)\
    .filter(AlertTypes.alert_type_long_des == 'Park Closed').first()

closed_parks = session.query(Parks)\
    .filter(Parks.alerts.any(alert_type = park_closed_alert )).all()
```

to get a list of ALL the closed parks...

but what if I've already retrieved a specific park, and I then want to check to see if it's closed?  Or to see if maybe multiple alerts (relationships) exists for a specific criteria.

```
park_record_from_db = session.query(Parks).filter(Parks.longdes == 'City Park').first()
```

`park_record_from_db.alerts` will give me a list of alerts, and I can easily iterate through them... But since calling the `.alerts` relationship will query the DB again anyways, can I just pass in the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with [dynamic relationship loaders](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/collections.html#dynamic-relationship-loaders). Specify `lazy=dynamic` when defining the relationship. The property will then behave as a [`Query`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query) object that can be filtered rather than loaded immediately.

```
alerts = relationship('Alerts', back_populates='park', lazy='dynamic')
[...]
filtered_alerts = park_record_from_db.alerts.filter( \
    Alerts.alert_type.in_((park_closed_alert, park_dogs_alert))).all()
```

Another option is [query-enabled properties](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#building-query-enabled-properties) which allows more customization.

Of course, if you want to filter by relationship at the point where you retrieve the initial object, you can use the [`any`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html?highlight=has#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any) operator:

```
park_record_from_db = session.query(Parks) \
    .filter(Parks.longdes == 'City Park') \
    .filter(Parks.alerts.any( \
        Alerts.alert_type.in_((park_closed_alert, park_dogs_alert)))) \
    .first()
```