# SQLAlchemy using like on relationship within a filter

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

EDIT: This is very similiar to [SqlAlchemy - Filtering by Relationship Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561470/sqlalchemy-filtering-by-relationship-attribute) in that we are both trying to filter on relationship attributes. However, they are filtering on matching an exact value, whereas I am filtering by using like/contains. Because of this, as pointed out in the comments, my solution requires an extra step that was not apparent in the other post.

Let me preface this with: I'm still quite new to SQLAlchemy, so it's entirely possible I'm going about this in the exact wrong way.

I have a Flask API that has defined "alerts" and "events". An alert can only belong to a single event, and an event can have multiple alerts. The schema for the alerts is as follows:

```
class Alert(PaginatedAPIMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'alert'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    type = db.relationship('AlertType')
    type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('alert_type.id'), nullable=False)
    url = db.Column(db.String(512), unique=True, nullable=False)
    event_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('event.id'), nullable=False)
    event = db.relationship('Event')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.url)

    def to_dict(self):
        return {'id': self.id,
                'event': self.event.name,
                'type': self.type.value,
                'url': self.url}
```

One of the API endpoints lets me get a list of alerts based on various filter criteria. For example, get all alerts of alert_type X, or get all alerts with X inside their alert_url. However, the one that is stumping me is that I want to be able to get all alerts with X inside their associated event name.

Here is the API endpoint function (the commented out events bit is my initial "naive" approach that does not work due to event being a relationship), but you can get the idea what I'm trying to do with the filtering.

```
def read_alerts():
    """ Gets a list of all the alerts. """

    filters = set()

    # Event filter
    #if 'event' in request.args:
    #    filters.add(Alert.event.name.like('%{}%'.format(request.args.get('event'))))

    # URL filter
    if 'url' in request.args:
        filters.add(Alert.url.like('%{}%'.format(request.args.get('url'))))

    # Type filter
    if 'type' in request.args:
        type_ = AlertType.query.filter_by(value=request.args.get('type')).first()
        if type_:
            type_id = type_.id
        else:
            type_id = -1
        filters.add(Alert.type_id == type_id)

    data = Alert.to_collection_dict(Alert.query.filter(*filters), 'api.read_alerts', **request.args)
    return jsonify(data)
```

The filters set that is built gets fed to the to_collection_dict() function, which essentially returns a paginated list  of the query with all of the filters.

```
def to_collection_dict(query, endpoint, **kwargs):
    """ Returns a paginated dictionary of a query. """

    # Create a copy of the request arguments so that we can modify them.
    args = kwargs.copy()

    # Read the page and per_page values or use the defaults.
    page = int(args.get('page', 1))
    per_page = min(int(args.get('per_page', 10)), 100)

    # Now that we have the page and per_page values, remove them
    # from the arguments so that the url_for function does not
    # receive duplicates of them.
    try:
        del args['page']
    except KeyError:
        pass
    try:
        del args['per_page']
    except KeyError:
        pass

    # Paginate the query.
    resources = query.paginate(page, per_page, False)

    # Generate the response dictionary.
    data = {
        'items': [item.to_dict() for item in resources.items],
        '_meta': {
            'page': page,
            'per_page': per_page,
            'total_pages': resources.pages,
            'total_items': resources.total
        },
        '_links': {
            'self': url_for(endpoint, page=page, per_page=per_page, **args),
            'next': url_for(endpoint, page=page + 1, per_page=per_page, **args) if resources.has_next else None,
            'prev': url_for(endpoint, page=page - 1, per_page=per_page, **args) if resources.has_prev else None
        }
    }
    return data
```

I understand that I can get the filtered list of alerts by their associated event name doing something along these lines with options and contains_eager:

```
alerts = db.session.query(Alert).join(Alert.event).options(contains_eager(Alert.event)).filter(Event.name.like('%{}%'.format(request.args.get('event')))).all()
```

But I have not gotten something similar to that to work when added to the filters set.

Comment: Probably very much related, if not a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561470/sqlalchemy-filtering-by-relationship-attribute. In short, do `filters.add(Alert.event.has(Event.name.contains(request.args.get('event'))))`. You could do the same with the `type` as well, removing the need to do a separate query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SqlAlchemy - Filtering by Relationship Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561470/sqlalchemy-filtering-by-relationship-attribute)

Comment: @IljaEverilä Funny thing is that I looked at that exact post yesterday thinking it was what I needed, but for some reason it didn't click due to the "Event.name.contains" bit. Anyway, you're right, and that worked perfectly! Thanks!