# SQLAlchemy relationship selection criteria

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have two model classes:

```py
class Programs(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "programs"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    duration = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DATE, default=datetime.now())
    created_by = db.Column(db.String(100))
    program_sessions = db.relationship('Program_Session',backref='programs')
   
class Program_Session(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "program_session"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    session_title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    session_description = db.Column(db.String(100))
    session_year = db.Column(db.Integer)
    program_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("programs.id"), nullable=False)
    students = db.relationship('Student_Registration', backref='program_session')
    date_created = db.Column(db.DATE, default=datetime.now())
    created_by = db.Column(db.String(100))
```

I create an object of Programs with:

```py
program = Programs.query.first()
```

Now I can access all the Program_Sessions from the selected Program:

```py
print(pro.program_sessions)
```

**Is it possible to subquery/query to retrieve only those Program_session in Program whose year is 2021?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SqlAlchemy - Filtering by Relationship Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561470/sqlalchemy-filtering-by-relationship-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

#### Option-1: filter on 'python' (in memory)

Once you get all Program_Sessions (`all_sessions = pro.program_sessions`), you filter them by `sessions_2021 = [item for item in all_sessions if item.session_year == 2021]`.

*Needless to say, this is not efficient at all as lots of data will be loaded from the database to be immediately discarded*.

#### Option2: use [Dynamic Relationship Loaders](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/collections.html#dynamic-relationship-loaders)

Define the relationship with `lazy="dynamic"`, which will return a `Query` and hence you will be able to apply additional criteria to the query:

```
class Programs(db.Model):
    # ...
    program_sessions = db.relationship('Program_Session', backref='programs', lazy="dynamic")

program = Programs.query.first()
sessions_2021 = program.program_sessions.filter(Program_Session.year == 2021).all()
```

#### Option3: use [orm.with_parent](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.with_parent) [BEST]

```
sessions_2021 = select(Program_Session).where(with_parent(program, Program_Session.programs)).where(Program_Session.year == 2021)
```

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is yes...**

[van's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67487401/4498470) answer shows you options for playing with sqlalchemy's query mechanism. But what if you want to write this logic on the `Programs` class itself? That way anywhere you have a `Programs` object, you can access the filter.

You can do it in **pretty plain python** by altering the Programs class like so:

```py
class Programs(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "programs"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    duration = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DATE, default=datetime.now())
    created_by = db.Column(db.String(100))
    program_sessions = db.relationship('Program_Session',backref='programs')
    
    '''Here I add a filter that returns only the sessions for a particular year
    '''
    def program_sessions_by_year(self, year):
        return filter(lambda ps: ps.session_year == year, self.program_sessions)
```

**If you care about efficiency**, you can get the database to do the filtering for you using a bit more sqlalchemy magic:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import object_session

class Programs(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "programs"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    duration = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DATE, default=datetime.now())
    created_by = db.Column(db.String(100))
    program_sessions = db.relationship('Program_Session',backref='programs')
    
    '''Improve efficiency by using DB's SQL engine to filter the object.
    '''
    def program_sessions_by_year(self, year):
        return object_session(self)\
                 .query(Program_Session)\
                     .filter_by(session_year=year, program_id=self.id)\
                         .all()
```

Either way you can then write (where-ever you have a `Program` object):

```py
# lets say you just want the first program
first_program = Programs.query.first()
# to get the program sessions by year 2021
first_program.program_sessions_by_year(2021)
```

There's probably a bunch of other ways you could do something like this. SqlAlchemy is a big library. For more background on my answer, have a look at the [SQL expressions as Mapped Attributes docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html).